# Xcode: Why won't my launch arguments work while recording UI tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

As I am planning to setup UI tests into my app, and using launch arguments to mockup some data, I realized something while building a simple test project:

**In the app target:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let uiTesting = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("ui-testing")
        view.backgroundColor = uiTesting ? .yellow : .white
    }
}
```

**In the UI test target:**

```
class UITestWithLaunchArgumentsProjectUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments.append("ui-testing")
        app.launch()
    }


    func testExample() {
        sleep(20)
    }
}
```

Thanks to this, I realized that if I run `testExample()` the background color becomes yellow as expected. However, when I use the record UI test tool, it doesn't.

Does anyone know why, and eventually how to use launch arguments also while recording UI tests?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is when you use record UI tool, it is not using the testSetup but run the app directly. In other words, you haven't tested it but extracting testing information from a normal app run.

A simple way to is to add ui-testing in the run scheme. So you can see yellow color as you want.

[image]

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks!